# transform weibull distributed data to change the scale

Tags: probability-distributions, transformation

For my study I need to provide a data set that includes three weibull distributed samples with the same shape, but different scale.

In the best case, I want to do a transformation onto one sample, to get as a result a sample with the same shape, but another scale. Is this possible?

(Additional:

I assume, I need to find an equation, that I can solve for the scale, and then use it as transformation, but I am a little lost, to find the equation to start with. I have tried the PDF, but I am not able to solve it for the scale (nor is the software I used).

The lecturer does not allow to generate a random sample and I do not want to lie. Besides I assume I am expected to learn something by this, but I am not able to see it until now.)

Comment: Please help me improving my first question in this SE instead of simple downvote it... I am willing to learn, how the questions should be shaped here!

Answer (score 1):

If $X\sim Weib(\lambda=1,k)$ we have
$$\mathbb P(X<t)=1-e^{-t^k}.$$

Your goal, if I have well understood is to arrive to a generic Weibull distribution, where,
$$\mathbb P(f(X)<t)=1-e^{-(t/\lambda)^k}$$
applying a function $f$ on $X$. Now, consider that for any random variable $Y$ with distribution $F_Y$ and any $a>0$ we have
$$F_{aY}(t)=\mathbb P(aY<t)=\mathbb P(Y<t/a)=F_Y(t/a)$$

Comment: why did you choose alpha = 1?

Comment: Just as base case, with the transformation suggested you can change it to every other positive number

Comment: I am sorry, that I do not understand your answer in all steps. What I am searching for, in your equations, is f(X), with k and t stays the same, but alpha changes. I can not connect the third equation with this... Thank you in any case for the answer itself :)